# Mylyn & Redmine Integration

Tags: redmine, mylyn

I'm trying to get Mylyn and Redmine work together so I can manage tasks right inside Eclipse. I saw this on redmine wiki http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/HowTo_Mylyn but I think it's for the old version of Mylyn.

I can't find the Generic Web Connector plugin for Mylyn but there's this Web templates plugin. I think that one replaced the Generic Web Connector. But it's quite different from the screenshots posted at the Redmine wiki. There's no Task URL, New Task URL, etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/redmin-mylyncon/

A Mylyn connector specially for RedMine. It works fine with eclipse ganymede.

The update site is: http://redmin-mylyncon.sourceforge.net/update-site/N/

Comment: Beware this only works with Redmine 0.9.x, not TRUNK or 0.8.*. It is nice though I have been using for awhile now.

Comment: The update site listed above has changed. Use this now: http://redmin-mylyncon.sourceforge.net/update-site/N/

Comment: And now the update site has been completely deleted. See http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3441532&group_id=228995&atid=1075435

Comment: The Redmine plugin has moved (or been mirrored) to git and requires Redmine 2.0.0 or greater: https://github.com/danmunn/redmine_mylyn_connector

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps to perform integration between Eclipse Mylyn and Redmine.
I assume that Eclipse, Mylyn and Redmine are already installed, the latter somewhere in $REDMINE_HOME. Tested with Eclipse 3.7 and Redmine 1.2.1.

Summarily, you need to install an Eclipse plugin AND a Redmine plugin.

1. Go to $REDMINE_HOME/vendor/plugins and run

   `git clone git://redmin-mylyncon.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/redmin-mylyncon/redmine-mylyn-connector`
2. (Re)start the server, and in Redmine under Administration/Plugins the Mylyn Connector Plugin should be listed
3. Again in Redmine, under Administration/Settings/Authentication, check the "Enable REST web service" field
4. In Eclipse, install the Eclipse connector via its update site

   http://redmin-mylyncon.sourceforge.net/update-site/N/
5. Create your repository and check that it connects, then you are good to go!

Answer (score 5):

See this manual. 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_Extensions

Eclipse Menu. 
Help -> Software Updates ... -> Add Site...

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator

Answer (score 5):

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn
http://danmunn.github.com/redmine_mylyn_connector/
https://github.com/danmunn/redmine_mylyn_connector

As of july 2012 now there is a new dedicated Redmine-Mylyn-Connector under active development for Redmine 2.x! (Got to admit, I haven't tested it yet.)

---

I am in the process of testing the 1.x connector that can be found on sourceforge, I will edit this post once I am done.

EDIT:
The update-site for the mylyn-plugin from the link in the accepted posting works.
As well as the mylyn-connector for the redmine installation. (Tested with 1.3.2 installation, don't forget to restart the web server after installing it. ;))

But both things aren't working out... once the mylyn-connector is installed, the web-interface is not working anymore. ;(

EDIT2:
The special connector works with 2.x and Mylyn finally looks proper.

http://danmunn.github.com/redmine_mylyn_connector/ the redmine server plugin.
http://kenjiru.ro/blog/2012/02/install-the-redmine-mylyn-connector-for-eclipse another server plugin link and the eclipse connector plugin

Will look like [this](http://mattanjakern.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/mylyn-redmine1.png).

Answer (score 4):

As of yesterday, Sven has taken down the update site (if you go there, you'll find nothing) since someone reported him to Sourceforge (see https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3441532&group_id=228995&atid=1075435).

So, there are NO binaries available now for Eclipse. Does anyone know of alternative ways to get these plugins? I have no clue how to compile.

The GIT and SVN repositories are there, but again as I sad, I'm not a java programmer. Can anyone offer Sven a site where he can store the binaries as an Update?

Answer (score 2):

For retrieve redmine mylyn connector

https://github.com/ljader/redmine-mylyn-plugin

In eclipse juno 4.2
"Install new software" and as local archive like in this post :
[How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

Comment: I recommend linked Eclipse plugin ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also a good read from redmine.

HowTo connect a Mylyn repository to Redmine:
http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/HowTo_Mylyn

Answer (score 0):

download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator wont work anymore, for the new update sites look at http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/

The Web Connector could be found via http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.5

Comment: HRgiger : http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_Extensions#Redmine might hold valuable information, though I cannot validate this currently. Next time I have set up a new working install (have no need for it right now and no time at hand...), I will update this post. Thank you for informing me!