# Trying to install redmine mylyn connector for eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, redmine, mylyn, redmine-plugins

I am trying to set up the mylyn redmine connector in eclipse indigo.

I installed the plugin from here with no errors:

http://redmin-mylyncon.sourceforge.net/update-site/N/

When i then open the task respository view and try to add new task repository it does not give me an option for redmine connector, only bugzilla and trac. I as an alternative i could install incubator and use a generic web connector but i wanted to avoid this route.

My installed software on eclipse is:

- CollabNet Merge Client    2.2.4
- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers    1.4.2.20120213-0813
- Geronimo v2.1 Server Adapter  2.1.8
- JNA Library   3.2.7
- Mylyn Builds Connector: Hudson/Jenkins (Incubation)   0.9.1.v20120425-0100
- Mylyn Connector: Redmine  0.3.6.201202270649
- Mylyn Connector: Redmine - Redmine-Plugin-Support 0.1.0.201202270649
- Mylyn Context Connector: C/C++ Development    5.3.1.v20120425-0100
- Mylyn Context Connector: Plug-in Development  3.7.1.v20120425-0100
- Mylyn Reviews Connector: Gerrit (Incubation)  0.9.1.v20120425-0100
- Mylyn Tasks Connector: Trac   3.7.1.v20120425-0100
- Mylyn Versions Connector: CVS (Incubation)    0.9.1.v20120425-0100
- Mylyn Versions Connector: Git (Incubation)    0.9.1.v20120425-0100
- Subclipse (Required)  1.6.18
- Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional)    3.0.0
- Subversion Client Adapter (Required)  1.6.12
- Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter (Required)   1.6.17
- Subversion Revision Graph 1.0.9
- SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required)  1.6.15
- SVNKit Library    1.3.5.7406

Comment: Please have a look to this thread in which this question is answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498426/mylyn-redmine-integration